# Why was this comment removed?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

The question: [When to use ServiceLoader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52204709/when-to-use-serviceloader/)

The comments:

> -Please read What types of questions should I avoid asking? before attempting to ask more questions. Polling for recommendations, tutorials and examples is off-topic. *– feeling unwelcome*
>
> *(I can recall my deleted reply accurately)*
>   -The question is about the use cases of ServiceLoader. OP found it unclear and not covered in the docs. Use cases can be backed up by examples for a better understanding. *- Andrew Tobilko*
>
> -@AndrewTobilko - it is not any more on-topic, regardless of intent, which is pretty clear what they are polling for *– feeling unwelcome*

I am curious why the comment was removed and which flag was raised. The comment suggested a discussion and was neither rude nor offensive.

EDIT:

I feel like the discussion isn't over: there are 3 other users who didn't find the question an off-topic and added their reasonable answers.

If the comment were treated as no longer needed, why wouldn't they clear out the whole discussion?

Comment: Comments are ephemeral by nature, you know that.

Comment: If i were to guess, i'd say someone flagged it as no longer needed. and... since it's not asking for more information from the op, it isn't needed.

Comment: i mean, people answer off topic questions all the time.. that's not really much of an indicator of anything.

Comment: I too see this as a reasonable question.  The documentation isn't entirely transparent about its usage and it's not wholly clear what purpose it suits.  We wouldn't have had a reasonable answer provided if it were left to the commentator and the question was outright closed.  I concur with you that if your comment was removed, *all* of them should have been.  Better yet, the most offensive part of the question could be remedied with a simple edit - I'll just take care of that and...the major impetus to close the question is now gone.

Comment: People can't quite seem to decide whether or not you're supposed to discuss the on-topicness of a question in the comments.

Comment: Regarding the actual question, VGR's answer contains a list of use cases (which is also what the question directly / indirectly asks for) - that makes me think the question is too broad.

Comment: I'm no Java expert, but a simple search on "ServiceLoader" on Google found [this question, which appears to ask almost exactly the same thing, except with a lot more prior research](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45387473/215552)...

Answer (score 2):

Two of the comments were flagged, the flags were handled by two separate moderators. I was the second one and a third moderator deleted the third comment. I probably should have deleted it, as it made no sense on its own.

I wouldn't exactly call it a discussion.

[image]

Comment: The whole point of my comment was to keep the question open. I am glad it was reopened, so this thread was helpful. Regarding the deletion, I got used to it: I often have my replies removed for no reason